# How to rotate an element in a Titanium Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, rotation, titanium

I have an application in Titanium for Android and iOS and it works ok. Now, I want to create the blackberry version.

In my app, I rotate some elements to create the interface.

For this, I use:

```
var matrix = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
matrix = matrix.rotate(value);
animationRotate = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    transform : matrix,
    duration : duration,
    autoreverse : false,
    repeat : 0
});

animationRotate.anchorPoint = {
    x : xAnchorPoint,
    y : yAnchorPoint
};

element.anchorPoint = {
    x : xAnchorPoint,
    y : yAnchorPoint
};

element.animate(animationRotate);
```

I've tried it on Blackberry simulator and I receive an error: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix NOT SUPPORTED IN BB10 (as it's said in documentation).

How can I rotate an element in BB10?

Thank you very much

Comment: You may need to look into writing your own module for Blackberry to allow you to do that.  Unfortunately, doesn't appear it is supported by Titanium yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found that it's possible to write a module for Blackberry in Titanium: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/BlackBerry_Module_Development_Guide. What do you refer it's not possible? Writing a module or do that in a module? Thank you very much

Comment: I just haven't worked with the Blackberry portion of modules in the past, so I wasn't aware if it was supported yet.  I have only used IOS and Android ones.  I wasn't aware of that document you found.